# Remove a toggle class when clicking another toggle link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am making a tumblr theme and have managed to have 3 toggle links. They are working fine but I was wondering if it were possible to make it so the if the first toggle link is open, and i click on a second toggle link, the first one will close, instead of just stacking up?

Relevant code:

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".changer").click(function(){
        $(".slidey").toggleClass("change_it");
    });
    $(".changer2").click(function(){
        $(".slidey2").toggleClass("change_it");
    });
    $(".changer3").click(function(){
        $(".slidey3").toggleClass("change_it");
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<li><a href="#" class="changer"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Mail</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="changer2"><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i> Links</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="changer3"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Blogroll</a></li>


   <div class="slidey">
       Yo yo
   </div>
   <div class="slidey2">
       linkies
   </div>
   <div class="slidey3">
       blogroll
   </div>
```

[here is the page](http://chloe784.tumblr.com)

It should also be noted that I am not very good with js/ jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup. Use it this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".changer").click(function(){
    if ($(".slidey" + $(this).data("slidey")).hasClass("change_it"))
    {
      $(".slidey" + $(this).data("slidey")).removeClass("change_it");
      return false;
    }
    $(".slidey1, .slidey2, .slidey3").removeClass("change_it");
    $(".slidey" + $(this).data("slidey")).addClass("change_it");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; text-decoration: none;}
.change_it {font-weight: bold;}

.tabs, .tabs li {display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-slidey="1"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Mail</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-slidey="2"><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i> Links</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-slidey="3"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Blogroll</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="slidey1">Slidey 1</div>
<div class="slidey2">Slidey 2</div>
<div class="slidey3">Slidey 3</div>
```

Comment: Use it that way! Welcome! `:)`

Comment: @chloe784 Don't forget to tick the answer in 10 mins... `:)`

Comment: @chloe784 Please click on the tick mark that is present on the left side of my answer to make it as accepted answer.

Comment: Just encountered a slight problem, how do you make it so that if you click on the same link it will close it? at this point there is no way to close them completely

Comment: Will accept when it works completely :) And no the change didn't help

Comment: Did you check the fiddle?

Comment: @chloe784 You there? Did the fiddle work? Can you please check it once again? Can you make your fiddle, so that I can work on it?

Comment: @chloe784 Can you try putting my code, so that I can check on the live site?

Comment: I don't know what i did differently but it works now! Thank you heaps - answer accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid code repetition adding a data-section referencing the id of the section you want to slide, otherwise youll be repeating yourself every time you want a new one.

So in your links:

```
<li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Mail</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#links"><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i> Links</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#blogroll"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Blogroll</a></li>
```

And your sections would look like:

```
<div id="blogroll">blogroll</div>
```

Finally your jquery code would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".changer").click(function() {

    var sectionToChange = $(this).data('section');

    $(".change_it:not("+sectionToChange+")").removeClass('change_it');

    $(sectionToChange).toggleClass("change_it");
  });
});
```

Thus avoiding the need to go back to it every time you create a new slidable section.

Update: A demonstration of the concept

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".changer").click(function() {

    var sectionToChange = $(this).data('section');

    $(".change_it:not("+sectionToChange+")").removeClass('change_it');

    $(sectionToChange).toggleClass("change_it");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.change_it {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tabs,
.tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#mail"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Mail</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#links"><i class="fa fa-link fa-fw"></i> Links</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#blogroll"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Blogroll</a>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#contacts"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Contacts</a>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#wiki"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> Wiki</a>
  </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="changer" data-section="#about"><i class="fa fa-th fa-fw"></i> About</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="mail">Mail</div>
<div id="links">Links</div>
<div id="blogroll">Blogroll</div>
<div id="contacts">Contacts</div>
<div id="wiki">Wiki</div>
<div id="about">About</div>
```

Comment: @chloe784 I updated the answer with a proof of concept. I dont mean to be rude but the accepted answer code is rather messy

Comment: @JSelser I don't consider you being rude. Can you explain why "messy"?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Half of what I said is because I missed the requirement of it being a toggle, I'll update my answer even if its pointless, my bad. Beyond that in `$(".slidey1, .slidey2, .slidey3").removeClass("change_it")` you are hardcoding existing slidey's so if you want to add a fourth you'll have to update the code, when it could be easily avoided(also the `if`). Chloe felt she was repeating code for every new slidey, and we know she's right because we ultimately want to write the code once to solve the problem for all actual and future slidey's in a general fashion. I meant to solve that.

Comment: i don't know what i'm supposed to do here, I just accepted the first code that worked for me. since i was only planning on having the few set slides the repetition didnt bother me, i haven't tried your code so i don't know if it would've worked in my situation. ?? Seriously lost?

Comment: @chloe784 It's no big deal, if you are planning on adding slidey's or reusing the code to have "sliding sections" in other pages you may benefit from my approach. To demonstrate, I updated my answer by adding the markup for 3 additional sections and they became "sliding sections" without having to change the JavaScript at all(click on "Run code snippet" to execute).